# Generating Views With Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3 When DbContext Uses Unity (Or Other Libraries)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having trouble running the "Generate Views" command from Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3 on a Code First `DbContext`. I get a dialog box indicating that an exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. The build output window does not contain any additional information. However, if I start commenting stuff out, I do get a `TargetInvocationException` reported in the build output window with a stack trace. It appears to get thrown any time my `DbContext` class accesses Unity - particularly in the `OnModelCreating()` method (we use IoC to put type configuration and other EF initialization code closer to the actual entity instead of sticking it all in the `DbContext` class).

I'm assuming the issue has something to do with the Entity Framework Power Tools being able to load the appropriate reference assemblies when the DbContext class makes use of third-party libraries. Does anyone have any thoughts about how to get around this? Is using Entity Framework Power Tools with DbContexts that use additional libraries a known problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I created a T4 template for generating views. You can try that. Here are more details: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/

Comment: @Pawel - I tried it out and it works great - thanks for putting that together! If you post this as a regular answer, I'd be happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a T4 template for generating views for Code First I posted on VS Gallery some time ago. You can find more details [here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/).